# Is there a software or means that can generate piper diagrams without some data?

Tags: water, software, visualization

I have cation and anion water chemistry data for some samples and I intend(ed) to generate [piper diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_diagram) for the same.

However, data for some parameters was not obtained during the determinations of the abovementioned and the software I am using won't generate a piper diagram without data for some parameters like sulfate.

Is there any way to generate the diagram without some data?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701429/library-tool-for-drawing-ternary-triangle-plots) are a number of good examples in Python and R. With open source, you can easily control what parameters to use and get a clear plot.

Comment: TikZ is another option [here](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/ternary-diagram/) is an example of a ternary diagram for inspiration, but actually, I think that [Peeters (2013) code](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/gwat.12118/abstract) will solve your problem.

Comment: Are you asking for software that can make plots without the data or how to fill in or estimate the missing data? You won't be able to plot a Piper diagram without sulfate (a Piper diagram is not the same as a ternary diagram). One thing you could do is to look at the charge balance and assume that any excess positive charge is balanced by the missing sulfate.

Comment: @haresfur the software would be ideal, but if non-existent I can work with a mathematical computation.

Comment: Calculate the mili-equivalents of each ion that you do know. Subtract the sum of the anions other than sulfate from the sum of the cations. Use that number to estimate your sulfate concentration.